# Anyway to clean the regex capture groups up?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to clean up this regex capture groups because it's capturing correctly just to me it's a strange return for `preg_match_all` strange to me since it's first time using `preg_match_all`

Test Code::
http://ideone.com/7NnrI1

**Regex**

```
/(?=<!--\sBEGIN\s(.*?)\s-->(.*?)(?=<!--\sEND\s(.*?)\s-->))/s
```

**Return**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 326
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => switch_legend
                [1] => 11
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => switch_default
                [1] => 337
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
<ul id="picture_legend">
    <li><img src="{FORUM_NEW_IMG}" alt="{L_NEW_POSTS}" />{L_NEW_POSTS}</li>
    <li><img src="{FORUM_IMG}" alt="{L_NO_NEW_POSTS}" />{L_NO_NEW_POSTS}</li>
     <li><img src="{FORUM_LOCKED_IMG}" alt="{L_LOCKED}" />{L_LOCKED}</li>
</ul>

                [1] => 28
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
<ul id="picture_legend">
    <li><img src="{FORUM_NEW_IMG}" alt="{L_NEW_POSTS}" />{L_NEW_POSTS}</li>
    <li><img src="{FORUM_IMG}" alt="{L_NO_NEW_POSTS}" />{L_NO_NEW_POSTS}</li>
     <li><img src="{FORUM_LOCKED_IMG}" alt="{L_LOCKED}" />{L_LOCKED}</li>
</ul>

                [1] => 355
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => switch_legend
                [1] => 308
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => switch_default
                [1] => 635
            )

    )

)
```

**Expected Return**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 0
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => switch_legend
                [1] => 11
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
<ul id="picture_legend">
    <li><img src="{FORUM_NEW_IMG}" alt="{L_NEW_POSTS}" />{L_NEW_POSTS}</li>
    <li><img src="{FORUM_IMG}" alt="{L_NO_NEW_POSTS}" />{L_NO_NEW_POSTS}</li>
     <li><img src="{FORUM_LOCKED_IMG}" alt="{L_LOCKED}" />{L_LOCKED}</li>
</ul>

                [1] => 28
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => switch_legend
                [1] => 308
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 326
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => switch_default
                [1] => 337
            )
         [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
<ul id="picture_legend">
    <li><img src="{FORUM_NEW_IMG}" alt="{L_NEW_POSTS}" />{L_NEW_POSTS}</li>
    <li><img src="{FORUM_IMG}" alt="{L_NO_NEW_POSTS}" />{L_NO_NEW_POSTS}</li>
     <li><img src="{FORUM_LOCKED_IMG}" alt="{L_LOCKED}" />{L_LOCKED}</li>
</ul>

                [1] => 355
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => switch_default
                [1] => 635
            )
    )

)
```

**What I need**

I would like the array to be clean from the matches, so that not each capture of the same pattern are in the same array rather each time it starts capturing it'll add to the same array like in the `Expected Return` Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like `PREG_SET_ORDER` is what you want.

Comment: Do I add it to the other flag in my `preg_match_all`?

Comment: Yup figured it out, please post your answer so I can happily give you your points.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `PREG_SET_ORDER` is what you want. –  mario